# CCLabelTTF changing string causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

First off, as a disclaimer, I am new to objective-c, xcode, and cocos2d. I have found a way in my app to refresh a screen conveniently, but I don't know if it is bad practice.  Here's what I am doing.  I have a class called Player with a variable NSString *name.  I am displaying this and several other variables on the screen using this code in a function:

```
label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:string fontName:GLOBAL_FONT fontSize:font_size ];
label.color = color_back;
label.position = ccp(x+1, y-1);
[self addChild:label];
```

When a button is pressed, I am modifying player->name along with several other variables. Because several variable are changing (on this screen and eventually others) when the button is pressed I also set a flag to indicate that the screen needs to be refreshed. I then check this code with a scheduler:

```
if(panelPrev != currentPanel || refreshScreen)    //do we need to initialize the panel?
{
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:true];     //clear all objects from display

    //Decide which objects to display
    switch (G_display_panel) {
        case P_Main:
            [Display_Main init_Panel:self];
            break;
        case P_NewGame:
            [Display_New init_Panel:self];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    refreshScreen = false;
}
```

My first question: Is this an acceptable way to display things to the screen and refresh them? It seemed much more convenient than updating every variable that is being displayed. The buttons are not being pressed very often so I am not concerned about performance.

Second: If it is ok to do it this way, why is it that when I press a button and change the value of player->name I am getting this: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...)"?  If I step through with the debugger the value gets assigned to player->name correctly and the screen refresh works. But if I just let it run it gets the EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to access player->name and the data looks corrupted (e.g. (NSString *) name = 0x15927f80 when I am expecting (NSString *) name = @"Bob").

Some additional details.

- I am not setting refreshScreen to 'true' until after changing the value of player->name
- To prevent refreshing before the value was truly changed, I set a delay on the refresh. After the button was pressed I would modify player->name and wait about 10 seconds but I would still see the same problem.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was a memory management issue. I added a getter and setter for the variable using the example specified here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was a memory management issue. I added a getter and setter for the variable using the example specified here: developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/… –

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[self addChild:label];
```